# Bottom-up level order of tree

Tags: java, casting

```
    Iterator itr=s.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        if(itr.next()==null)
            System.out.println();
        else
        {
          ArrayList al2=(ArrayList)itr.next();
            for(int i=0;i<al2.size();i++)
                System.out.println(al2.get(i));

        } 
    }

}//function close
```

Here I tried to push array lists into stack but when I am trying to access them through iterating nothing is getting printed.

Comment: Without knowing what ArrayLists you are iterating over it's impossible to tell. Most likely there either are no arrayLists to iterate over or all the ArrayLists are simply empty (size=0) so your print statement is never reached.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell for sure without seeing the input you are dealing with but one problem in your code is the use of `itr.next()`. That method will return the next item in the list **and advance the iterator**. So, because you are calling it twice per loop, you are taking two items from the list on each pass. You should re-organize your code so that you are only calling `next()` once per pass:

```
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    ArrayList al2=(ArrayList)itr.next();
    if (al2 == null) {
        System.out.println("List contained null value");
    }
    for (Object obj: al2) {
        System.out.println("List entry: " + obj);
    }
}
```